# MKOverlayView draw something with blend mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cgcontext, mapkit

I want to draw map overlay with blend mode. But this code just draw white overlay without any blend mode. What I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSaturation);
    CGContextFillRect(context, [self rectForMapRect:mapRect]);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Here is result that I want. I make it in Photoshop with three layers:

1. original google map.
2. black layer with saturation blend mode.
3. white layer with exclusion blend mode.
   [image]

Comment: MKOverlayView sits on top of the map.  Any effects you apply to the overlay's context will only affect the overlay.  If you can be more specific on what effect you wish to achieve I think you'll get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you cannot acces the real mapview context directly. So probably you have to take a "screenshot" of the map and draw it again in your context. After that you can apply your effects of course.

Comment: It seems pretty complicated to do this with movable map. My idea was to use overlay tiles to add effect to map.

Comment: you could show the normal map while scrolling and as soon, as the map stops moving, you take a screenshot and apply your effects. If you apply a little fade animation as transition, this could look nice, I guess.

Comment: Idea was to show smooth black map. But as I now understand it's too tough to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to design your own maps with openstreetmap and a wms server or with a service like mapbox and than add this custom map as overlay.

Here is an example on how to add other maps as overlays: https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo